# How can we stack rows of data excluding blank under one header/column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the link. I want to show three different types of particulars under one column with repetition of customer IDs on Google Sheets. Here is the link of the sample data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pri0RnWP6dp86yYz_6T3rvNcU4XhvrCFGwmvaHmjHI/edit?usp=sharing

My data is

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should produce the behaviour you desire:

```
=QUERY({A2:E;{A2:B,F2:H}},"select * where Col3 is not null order by Col1")
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the solution it works, however if I want to add more columns in my data set/table and then perform the same exercise , can you advise how can we proceed further or the changes required in the formula? Thanks again for your help

Comment: If you wanted to add a third particular (Ex: Particular: "Third" with an Amount 3 and Date 3 column), you would modify the first portion of the query to include the additional rows. `=QUERY({A2:E;{A2:B,F2:H};{A2:B,I2:K}}`. Or for a fourth particular, `=QUERY({A2:E;{A2:B,F2:H};{A2:B,I2:K};{A2:B,L2:N}}`, etc. @ranjanaraghav

Comment: Thank you so so so so much. It worked. I was stuck on this for a long while now. Genuinely appreciate your help here. You are amazing!! I will reach out to you if I get stuck on further problems like these, THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I got stuck again the customer ID which is alphanumeric or special character it takes it as blanks while using the formula- Is there any way around this? Sorry for the bother Thanks!

Comment: @ranjanaraghav I'm not quite sure what you mean. Perhaps it might be a good idea to create a new question post? This seems like a substantially different issue to your previous one.