# Split Google Form response to rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form with multiple sections. Section 1 is just a date input.

Section 2 - 13 are exactly the same as each other, they have the following example questions:

- Colour
- Size
- Age
- City
- Another? [yes/no]

Saying yes on the final question proceeds to the next section, therefor allowing you to capture another "set" of data. Saying no submits the form.

My form submission thus looks something like this in the `Responses` sheet:

| Timestamp | Date | Colour | Size | Age | City | Another | Colour | Size | Age | City | Another | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/07/2022 21:09:19 | 21/07/2022 | Blue | XL | 25 | NY | Yes | Red | S | 22 | TX | Yes |  |

The columns Colour, Size, Age, City and Submit thus repeat in the columns, either with data or blank - depending on how many times Yes was selected at the end of the sections.

What I am trying to do is turn every "set" of Colour, Size, Age and City into a row of it's own on another sheet. So the final sheet would look like this:

| Timestamp | Date | Colour | Size | Age | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/07/2022 21:09:19 | 21/07/2022 | Blue | XL | 25 | NY |
| 25/07/2022 21:09:19 | 21/07/2022 | Red | S | 22 | TX |
| etc... |  |  |  |  |  |

The timestamp and date should be at the start of every row, while the respective sets of Colour, Size, Age and City are appended to the bottom of this new `Data` sheet with every form submission.

I would also want to avoid blank rows, so only append to the `Data` sheet if there are values in the sets of responses.

Any assistance for how this google script should look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"...looks something like this..."* Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Is it a requirement that this result be achieved through Google Apps Script? If not, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749390/how-can-we-stack-rows-of-data-excluding-blank-under-one-header-column/72749807#72749807) might be helpful to you.

Comment: If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in Apps Script:

```js
function splitFormResponses() {
  const rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("formReponses");
  const responses = rs.getRange(2, 1, rs.getLastRow() -1, rs.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  const splittedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("splittedResponses");
  const splittedResponses = [];
  var newResponse = [];
  var timestamp;
  var date;

  //Creating a 2D array using the amount of rows in the responses.
  for(i=0; i < responses.length; i++){
    
    //Loop through each cell in the row.
    for (j = 0; j < responses[i].length; j++) { 
      timestamp = responses[i][0];
      date = responses[i][1];

      //If there is "another" it will add the created row to the 2D array and restart the "newResponse" variable with the current row's timestamp and date
      if (responses[i][j] == "Yes") {

        splittedResponses.push(newResponse);
        newResponse = [timestamp, date];

      //If there is no "another" it will add the created row to the 2D array and jump to the next row in the original responses.
      } else if (responses[i][j] == "No"){

        splittedResponses.push(newResponse);
        newResponse = [];
        break;     

      //Otherwise, it will add the value of the current cell to the new row.
      } else { 

      newResponse.push(responses[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  //Printing the array.
  splittedSheet.getRange(2, 1, splittedResponses.length, splittedResponses[0].length).setValues(splittedResponses);
}
```

Using this example data:

[image]

You get this result in a new "splittedResponses" sheet at "A2".

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I will just look at running this on new form submission, then it's perfect.