# Split Google Form response to rows by sections with constant header columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form with multiple sections and constant information on section 1 (A:E).
Sections 2 -6 are repetitions of same questions.

Saying yes on the final question proceeds to the next section and I want to turn every set of questions into a row of answers with constant information (section 1) repeated for each row.

Here's a link to my response sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GFZUN2zQinZJWTV717andSyBW_01b0Rz5RGZb4SddoY/edit?usp=sharing

I realize my question is very similar to this post but I don't have Apps Script knowledge to modify to fit my needs. [Split Google Form response to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114645/split-google-form-response-to-rows/73115665?newreg=6939e39d93ff4baf93eef5bcd92dd678)

Can someone help me achieve this? It doesn't have to be a script but a query as well.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Saying yes on the final question proceeds to the next section and I want to turn every set of questions into a row of answers with constant information (section 1) repeated for each row.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a resources-consuming solution if you have many rows. But here's an option with formula:

```
=REDUCE(formReponses!A1:N1,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(formReponses!A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,v,VSTACK(a,
REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(formReponses!1:1)/10),1,0),LAMBDA(b,c,
IF(OFFSET(formReponses!A1,v,c*10+5)="",b,VSTACK(b,
  HSTACK(OFFSET(formReponses!A1,v,0):OFFSET(formReponses!E1,v,0),OFFSET(formReponses!A1,v,c*10+5):OFFSET(formReponses!A1,v,c*10+13)))))))))
```

[image]

PS: I assume you forgot a column of "Comments" between M and N column? I added it for my solution